# Extract text before the fullstop or colon

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr

I would like to extract part of the string, the tricky part is that, the text I want to extract is either before full stop or colon, so how do I make it work?

```
  city<- c('Kirkland-1234.It is a goodtown','Bethesda-345. small town', 'Wellington: 12345')
```

So I would like to get the text before the first fullstop or first colon. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or:

```
library(stringr)

city <- c('Kirkland-1234.It is a goodtown','Bethesda-345. small town', 'Wellington: 12345')

str_extract(city, "^[^\\.:]+")

#1] "Kirkland-1234" "Bethesda-345"  "Wellington"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` in base R

```
sub("(.*?)[\\.|:].*", "\\1", city)
#[1] "Kirkland-1234" "Bethesda-345"  "Wellington"
```

This extracts everything until  first occurrence of full-stop or colon.

Answer (score 0):

```
stringr::str_locate(TEXT,":|,")[1]
```

Is the code you want, now do you just have a list? Then use the above in lapply:

```
library(stringr)    
city_list <- lapply(city, str_locate,":|,")
cities <- lapply(city_list,`[[`, 1)
```

It might be even easier in a data frame:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
mutate(city = str_locate(city,":|,")[1])
```